# O que é uma Expression Language (EL)?

Tags: java, terminologia

Muito utilizada em `JSF`, as famosas Expression Languages(EL's) simbolizadas por `#{}`. Não sei se outras linguagens trabalham com a mesma. O que elas significam ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trecho adaptado diretamente da documentação da Oracle sobre [Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html):

EL = Expression Language  = Linguagem de expressão:

A EL permite que o desenvolvedor use simples expressões para acessar dinamicamente dados de componentes Beans (JavaBeans). Por exemplo, o atributo "test" da seguinte tag é preenchido com uma expressão EL que compara o com o numéro de itens do bean de sessão chamado Cart:

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.cart.numberOfItems > 0}">
  ...
</c:if>
```

Lembrando que EL não é de exlusividade do Java ou do JSF, você irá encontrar EL em diversas outras tecnologias como PHP e AngularJS por exemplo.

A tecnologia JavaServer Faces utiliza EL para as seguintes funções:

- Evaluação imediata ou tardia de expressões;
- Possibilidade de setar e buscar dados de Beans;
- Possibilidade de invocar metodos;

Resumindo:

A EL possibilita uma forma de utilizar simples expressões para comunicar os scripts de tela (XHTML, JSP ou outros) com o código Java que roda no servidor. Com isto é possível que possamos facilmente transmitir e manipular dados entre ambas camadas sem precisar nos preocuparmos com todo o empasse que ocorre entre ambas.

Comment: No seu exemplo você utiliza `${}` . Também se refere a uma EL ?

Comment: O trecho ${} é justamente a EL aplicada dentro da tag <c:if>!

Comment: Certo, eu achava que EL só trabalhava com `#{}` :)

Comment: EL podem ser trabalhadas de diversas formas, com Angular2 por exemplo utiliza-se `{{}}`.